# Basic probability question :- What is the probability that $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers not more than $6$, is a perfect square?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers not more than $6$, is a perfect square?

What is the fault in below logic of solving this question :-

Either we can have AB or BA as the numbers

AB = probability of choosing the first number (i.e. A) = 1, and probability of choosing B will be $\frac{1}{6}$

BA = probability of choosing the first number (i.e. B) = 1, and probability of choosing A will be $\frac{1}{6}$

$\frac{1}{6}$+$\frac{1}{6}$=$\frac{1}{3}$

Official answer is $\frac{2}{9}$

Comment: we can choose first number without any restriction thats why I took probability of choosing the first number as 1

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you wish to find the probability that the product of two numbers chosen from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ is a perfect square.  Do $a$ and $b$ have to be distinct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct; I know that I can list the sample space of all 36 pairs and then find which pairs give me perfect square, but what is the fault in above processing ?

Comment: There is no condition given whether they have to be distinct , so we can take them to be same as well

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $6^2 = 36$ possible ordered pairs $(a, b)$, where $a, b \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, giving $36$ possible products, not all of which are distinct.  Of these, there are eight ordered pairs whose product is a perfect square: $$(1, 1), (1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)$$  Therefore, the probability that $ab$ is a perfect square is
$$\frac{8}{36} = \frac{2}{9}$$

*What was wrong with your approach?*

It looks like you overlooked the two pairs $(1, 4)$ and $(4, 1)$ in which $a \neq b$.  If $a = 1$ or $a = 4$, the probability that a perfect square is obtained when $b$ is selected is $1/3$.  For the other four choices for $a$, the probability that a perfect square is obtained when $b$ is selected is $1/6$.  Notice that
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{2}{9}$$
Also, you counted each favorable pair twice, once as $(a, b)$ and once as $(b, a)$.

Answer (score 2):

Before we answer this question, we need to be clear about what we are asking. Based on the contents of your question, it seems like you want to know

> Suppose $A,B \in \{1, \cdots, 6\}$ are two random variables sampled uniformly from $\{1, \cdots, 6\}$. What is the probability that $AB$ is a perfect square?

First I'll give you one approach to solve this, then I'll come back and address your approach in your question.

Note the set of perfect squares $AB$ can be is $S := \{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36\}$. Since there are $36$ possible outcomes for $A$ and $B$ jointly, we have (informally)
$$\mathbb{P}[AB \in S] = \frac{\sum_{s \in S} \text{# of ordered ways to factor $s$ as a product of two numbers at most 6}}{36}$$
To deterimine the summands in the numerator above, we can proceed case-by-case:

- $1$ only factors as $1 \cdot 1$
- $4$ only factors as $1 \cdot 4$, $2 \cdot 2$, $4 \cdot 1$
- $9$ only factors as $3 \cdot 3$
- $16$ only factors as $4 \cdot 4$
- $25$ only factors as $5 \cdot 5$
- $36$ only factors as $6 \cdot 6$

This means the numerator is $8$, so the correct answer is $\frac{8}{36} = \frac{2}{9}$ (as you mentioned).

Now let's come back to your approach. The error should be able to be traced to miscounting the numerator term. From what I understand, your argument is effectively the following

> Choose any number for $A$. The probability of this event is $1$. Conditioned on that choice of $A$, the probability we choose $B$ so $AB$ is a perfect square is $\frac{1}{6}$ regardless of the choice of $A$.

This is incorrect. For $A=1$ or $A=4$, there are two choices for $B$ that will produce a perfect square. We can amend your argument by separating the $A = 1,4$ cases:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}[AB \in S] &= \mathbb{P}[AB \in S | A \in \{1,4\}] \mathbb{P}[A \in \{1,4\}] + \mathbb{P}[AB \in S | A \not\in \{1,4\}] \mathbb{P}[A \not\in \{1,4\}] \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \\
&= \frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{18} \\
&= \frac{2}{9}
\end{aligned}
$$

> Do the same for $B$. Add the two together to count all possibilities.

You do not need to add the two together. Looking at the possibilities for $A$, then the possibilities for $B$ conditioned on each choice of $A$ will count all choices for $A$ and $B$. Adding the two together will double count all possibilities and give you $2$ times the correct answer.